# Is it more efficient to declare helper functions outside the main function?

Tags: r, performance, functional-programming

When I debug step by step this kind of function:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  helper <- function(x) x^2
  2 * helper(x)
}
```

I see that the helper function definition is evaluated each time. Is it the same, when no in debug mode? Is it bad in terms of time execution?

Comment: Yes. No, not really. Defining a function is cheap compared to calling a function. I suggest you do some benchmarks to confirm that.

Comment: @Roland Cheaper than calling it, sure, but the cost is still nontrivial: R will evaluate the function definition *each time* the outer function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it yourself.  I didn't see much of a difference. inside or outside was faster on different runs when I tried it.

```
library(microbenchmark)

foo1 <- function(x) {
  helper <- function(x) x^2
  2 * helper(x)
}

helper <- function(x) x^2
foo2 <- function(x) {
  2 * helper(x)
}

microbenchmark(
  inside = foo1(1:1000),
  outside = foo2(1:1000),
  times = 1000
)
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see if switching off the JIT compiler changes the benchmarks.

Comment: @Roland Are functions that are sourced or entered in the REPL JITted? I thought only package loading caused JITtin  by default.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what happens in a case where the definition of `helper` is non-trivial.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not an expert for this. I know that the JIT compiler improves code called by loops. That code doesn't have to be from a package. (That's a reason why, since several R versions now, growing an object in a loop isn't always inefficient.)

Comment: @Roland Growing an object in a loop is inefficient because increasing memory gets copied around at every single iteration unless memory is reserved in increasing chunks. This isn’t something that can be fixed by a JIT, it’s fixed by progressively reserving memory in the receiving data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @John Coleman comment I have tried this:

```
library(microbenchmark)

foo1 <- function(x) {
  helper <- function(x) {
    nested_helper <- function(y) {
      depper_helper <- function(z) {
        z + z
      }
      3 * depper_helper(y)
    }
    nested_helper(x) ^ 2
  }
  2 * helper(x)
}


nested_helper <- function(y) {
  3 * depper_helper(y)
}
depper_helper <- function(z) {
  z + z
}
helper <- function(x) {
  nested_helper(x) ^ 2
}
foo2 <- function(x) {
  2 * helper(x)
}

microbenchmark(
  inside = foo1(1:1000),
  outside = foo2(1:1000),
  times = 1000000
)
```

I ran it two times and obtain the same results:

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr min  lq     mean median  uq     max neval
  inside 5.0 5.4 8.822796    5.8 8.5 50905.9 1e+06
 outside 4.9 5.2 8.559778    5.6 8.3 47797.3 1e+06
```

Inside definition seems a little bit slower but not in a significant way. There must be some kind of optimization by the JIT compiler. I would like confirmation of this.

Comment: `compiler::enableJIT(0)` switches the compiler off. The default is `compiler::enableJIT(3)`.  However, the function definitions are still not what we would consider nontrivial. I believe John means `helper` having a few hundred lines of code.